# Сохранить прогресс скролла NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, nested-scrollview

У меня есть `NestedScrollView`, в котором есть `TextView` с большим объемом текста, мне нужно событие прокрутки при остановки сохранять в `SharedPreferences`, возможно ли сделать такое не создавая отдельный класс, если нет, то как это сделать в отдельном классе, и как вообще это сделать лучше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Справился, сделал так:

Реализовал `setOnScrollChangeListener`:

```
mainNestedScroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            mEditor.putInt("ScrollX", scrollX);
            mEditor.putInt("ScrollY", scrollY);
            mEditor.apply();
        }
    });
```

И в методе `onResume`:

```
final int scrollX = mPreferences.getInt("ScrollX", 0);
final int scrollY = mPreferences.getInt("ScrollY", 0);

mainNestedScroll.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mainNestedScroll.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
    }
});
```